# Axios and CreateObjectURL: Correct way to download blob data? My attempt causes page reload

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, axios, createobjecturl

I have a button with a click event handler that, when clicked, will use axios to GET a file that resides on a remote server (passes a token and gets a `blob` responseType back). I don't understand how to use `Url.createObjectURL` with axios. What I am **trying to do** is have the browser download (or open?) a file when the user clicks the "download button" for that file. Unfortunately, my current attempt
causes the browser to **reload the page and append a `#` at the end** of my Single page application with what I think is a hashed string?

**How can I correctly download the file?**

Here's my attempt:

```
async getDownloadAttachmentApiUrl(e) {
  const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('my-token'))
  const bearer = 'Bearer ' + token[0].access_token
  console.log(e.target.innerText) // example: attachments/5424/5424/24252345085_9cc011f4df_o.jpg
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'my-api-domain-here',
    responseType: 'blob',
    headers: {
      Authorization: bearer,
    }
  })
  try {
    const response = await instance.get('/Attachment?attachment=' + e.target.innerText)
    const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(response.data)
    console.log(objectURL) // blob: https://lvh.me:8080/e6831f0d-b44f-4c50-b0c7-dc1389ee8cd7#/
```

The console log for `objectURL` is:
`https://lvh.me:8080/e6831f0d-b44f-4c50-b0c7-dc1389ee8cd7#/` which, when clicked, just causes the browser to reload the page and append the `#` at the end of the URL.

Here is the VueJS template code:

```
            <button v-for="(attachmentFileName, index) in attachmentsJsonObject.attachments" :key="index" @click.prevent="getDownloadAttachmentApiUrl">
              Download
            </button>
```

Thanks for any help/clarification on the proper way to set this up!